# css div width by inner div percentage

Tags: html, css

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="rightPanel" >
            <div class="rightPanelContent"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have a right sidebar like this and content of sidebar. `rightPanel` is not appearing at first. I did not set css Width size. When I click a menu, `rightPanelContent` is filling with html elements and rightPanel is opening.

So I do not want to set width of `rightPanel`(like 20% of page). I want to set `rightPanelContent` width percentage of main page 20%. But it is getting percentage of `rightPanel`, not getting page percentage.

Here is working code [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/6er0qseq/)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post sample code of how you are filling content, setting width etc. Better you add jsfiddle.

Comment: Please add your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and share link.

Comment: share a fiddle with us please..

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. What you want to do is absolute position the panel on the side and set its width to 20% then move it so its out of view (hiding it in the parents `overflow: hidden`. When the content starts going in just move the panel out.

Comment: Something like this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kc5ykhb/)

Comment: @bookmarker Look at my demo and click the text, it is absolute positioned.

Comment: I looked but there is no such think with my question

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to this

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="rightPanel" ></div>
        <div class="rightPanelContent"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

then set

```
 .rightPanelContent { width:20%}
```

if you want it to have 20% of the viewport

Use  [Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/)

```
 .rightPanelContent { width:20vw}
```